# How to return value from function which has Observable inside?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, angular2-observables

I need help in observable.

In function I Just need to return a value from observable.

Thanks in advance

```
getDate(): string {

      this.store.pipe(select(selectDate), map(dateFormat => {
            if (dateFormat) {
                return of(dateFormat);
            } else {
                return of('new Date');
            }
        }));
    }
```

Comment: Short answer: you don't. You can't return synchronous data from an asynchronous request. You need to return the `this.store...` observable and subscribe to it where the response string is required.

Comment: Valour do you need the value returned synchronously or asynchronously? As @MichaelD pointed out, it's not possible synchronously - but asynchronously, it's possible.